# How to remove eclipse editor's default context menu actions?

Tags: editor, contextmenu, eclipse-gef

I would like to remove (or make invisible) the default context menu actions from my custom GEF editor.
I have some custom actions (IAction) which I register (using createActions()) that I can see and run, however I would like to see only them on my context menu.

In other words - is there a way to remove "Run As", "Debug As", "Profile As", etc...?

[image]

In the image above, for example, I would like to display only "Delete" action.

Many thanks in advance... !

Comment: I created my own editor and these menu items are not there. How are you implementing your editor? did you base it on one of the example editors provided by GEF?

Comment: Yes. Inherit from GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette and added my editor to plugin.xml project

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have included ide plugins in your product.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use code like this to add your context menu:

```
MenuManager menuManager = new MenuManager();
Menu contextMenu = menuManager.createContextMenu(table);
table.setMenu(contextMenu);
getSite().registerContextMenu(menuManager, selectionProvider);
```

The last line is important. Replace it with

```
getEditorSite().registerContextMenu(menuManager, selectionProvider, false);
```

and the default entries will be gone.